# IDataErrorInfo reduce redundancy

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

**A code contains some redundant data how do i remove redundancy and simplify my code without changing its functionality..**

Also i wanted to know  the right way of implementing IDataErrorInfo

**public string Error** and **public string this[string columnName]** both property does the work of checking null values i dont want both to check for nulls.

Comment: How have you identified that there is redundant code, but yet you do not know what the code is? Is this a homework question?

Comment: no its not a homework question. i just dont want the redundant code.. i can tell from my implementation but i dont know how is it possible. **public string Error** and  **public string this[string columnName]** has the same code .

Comment: Please add more detail to your question about which parts exactly you think are redundant. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out @PeterBailey.. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's better to use validation attributes for that, but if speak about your concrete example - you can remove redundancy like this:

```
public string Error
{
    get { return this[null]; }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {                    
        if (columnName == null || columnName == "UnitCode") {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UnitCode)) {
                return "Unit Code cannot be empty";
            }
        }
        if (columnName == null || columnName == "UnitName") {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UnitName)) {
                return "Unit Name cannot be Empty";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Thank you** @Evk I am going to add my own logic and see if works.

Comment: I hope the principle is clear: when `columnName` is null in `this` indexer - that means "validate all columns".

Comment: Issue is resolved and thank you for the snippet. :) i never knew about this concrete way until now. yes principle is very much clear and understood.